# Why is $E:=\bigcup_{x_0\in M}I(x_0)\times\left\{x_0\right\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}\times M$ open?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $\dot{x}=f(t,x)$; assume that all conditions to apply the global existence theorem are fullfilled. Call $\theta_{(t_0,x_0)}\colon I(t_0,x_0)\to\mathbb{R}^N$ the unique maximal solution of the IVP with starting values  $(t_0,x_0)\in W$, where $I(t_0,x_0)$ is the maximal existing interval. Then 
$$ 
\Theta\colon\underbrace{\bigcup_{(t_0,x_0)\in W}I(t_0,x_0)\times\left\{(t_0,x_0)\right\}}_{=:\Omega}\to\mathbb{R}^N, \Theta(t,t_0,x_0):=\theta_{(t_0,x_0)}(t)
$$
is called the general solution of the ODE.

Notation in case of autonomous ODE: always choose $t_0=0$; set $\theta_{(0,x_0)}:=\theta_{x_0}, I(0,x_0):=I(x_0)$

There are theorems saying that $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2+N}$ is open and $\Theta$ is continious. So far so good.

---

Now consider $\dot{x}=f(x), f\colon M\to\mathbb{R}^N$, $M\subseteq\mathbb{R}^N$ open, f fullfilling all conditions to apply the global existence theorem. Consider
$$
E:=\bigcup_{x_0\in M}I(x_0)\times\left\{x_0\right\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}\times M.
$$

Now I would like to proof, that $E$ is open. But I do not know how to do so.

The script only says that this is rather easy and follows from the fact that $\Omega$ is open and that the general solution $\Theta$ is continious. Nonetheles, I do not see how to prove this. Not "rather easy" to me...

Can you please help me? Would be very nice of you.

With kind regards

math12

**Update**

Of course I tried a little bit. And this is my idea:

It is $E\subset\Omega$ and because $\Theta$ is continious, the restriction from $\Theta$ to $E$ is continious, too. Consider the topological spaces $(E,\mathcal{O}_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^N,\mathcal{O}_2)$, where $\mathcal{O}_1$ is the subspace topology (i.e. the product topology on $\mathbb{R}\times M$, restricted to $E$) and $\mathcal{O}_2$ the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Because $\Theta_{|E}$ is continious and $\mathbb{R}^N\in\mathcal{O}_2$ (i.e. is open), $E=\Theta_{|E}^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is open.

Another idea, without using the continuity of $\Theta_{|E}$, is, that $E\in\mathcal{O}_1$ of course. So it's open.

Maybe you can say if I wrote nonsense or at least a bit right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that $E$ is the intersection of $\Omega$ with the subset $t=0$ in $M\times \mathbb R^2$, where $t$ is the first of two coordinates in $\mathbb R^2$. In a formula, 
$$E = \Omega\cap (M\times \{0\}\times \mathbb R)$$
Therefore, $E$  is open in the induced topology of the subset $M\times \{0\}\times \mathbb R$. But on the other hand, $M\times \{0\}\times \mathbb R$  is naturally identified with $M\times \mathbb R$.

Comment: I think I got your point, thank you. I would write it a little bit different: It is $E=\Omega\cap Z$ with $Z:=\left\{(t,t_0,x_0)\in\Omega: t_0=0\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}\times\left\{0\right\}\times M\subset\mathbb{R}^2\times M$. Now $\Omega$ is within the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^2\times M$ and so $E=\Omega\cap Z$ is within the topology on $\mathbb{R}\times\left\{0\right\}\times M$ (the induced topology). Because $\mathbb{R}\times\left\{0\right\}\times M=\mathbb{R}\times M$, $E$ is within the topology on $\mathbb{R}\times M$, which means, that $E$ is open in $\mathbb{R}\times M$. Okay?

Comment: Then it is better to write $\mathbb{R}\times\left\{0\right\}\times M\cong\mathbb{R}\times M$? Can you tell me which exactly this isomorphism is?

Comment: Yes, my idea is $\phi\colon \mathbb{R}\times\left\{0\right\}\times M\to\mathbb{R}\times M, (t,0,m)\mapsto (t,m)$. This is obviously bijective. But why is it a homomorphism?